# How to set domain name for server running on ip address

Tags: linux, unix, dns, ip-address

Right now server is accessed via IP Address http://10.1xx.19.2xx:8080/svn

How can i change it to http://domainname.com/svn ?

Which file to edit ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an A record in your DNS server mapping that hostname to your IP address.

You also need to configure your server to listen on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what service you have running behind port 8080. If it's apache, and /svn is a directory under your DocumentRoot, it's easy:

1. First, it appears you are using a private IP address (beginning with `10.xxx.xxx.xxx`) so you will need to discover if you have a public routing IP address mapped to `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` on your server. If you don't know you might try [one of these tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=determining%20a%20server%27s%20public%20ip%20address).
2. Register a domain name, and point its DNS `A` record to the public IP address of your server.
3. If you are using apache virtual hosting you will need to add `ServerName domainname.com` or `ServerAlias example.com` to the `<VirtualHost>` block in the apache configuration (or follow the equivalent process if you in your server control panel).
4. Restart apache, and wait for DNS propagation to complete (which takes up to 24 hours).

This will allow you to have access to `http://domainname.com:8080/svn`. If you want to access it without the `:8080` in the URL, you will need to run the service under port 80, the default for http, but this can't be done if another service is already running on port 80.

If you're not using apache, or you're using `dav_svn_module` or another tool to provide access to an svn repository, you'll need to describe your exact environment so you can get the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Quinn's answer, if you have admin access to an Apache server, you can also configure mod_proxy to proxy http://domainname.com/svn to http://10.1xx.19.2xx:8080/svn.  You'll probably end up using the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives.  Take a look at the Apache docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.